# Android TCP Urgent message implementation

Tags: android, tcp

There is the TCP URG flag that signa part of the TCP message as urgent.
In this case, the urgent part supposed to proceed faster and to arrived earlier to the application.
Is it related also to priority of the receiving application? Does it's priority changes because of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee that TCP packet with URG flag will arrive faster. This is because URG flag only affects TCP packets processing on receiving host and does not influence actual media transmission.

URG flag is used in out-of-band (OOB) messages processing. For instance if you're sending a large media stream of data and then want to cancel receive on the remote host. In this case you mark send as OOB. OOB data packet on receiver will be processed prior common data packets.

Can you be more specific about application priority? If you mean execution priority then I think URG TCP data will not affect app priority.

Comment: Thanks, That what I understood also